# Can we rank P-values from chi-square tests by magnitude (similar to correlation coefficient)

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test, p-value

A, B, C are categorical variables. A is a dependent variable against which I would like to find if B and C have any relationship.

Suppose P-value from a Chi-square test between categorical attribute A and B comes out to be 4%, and that between A and C comes out to be 1%.

- Is it correct to say C has higher impact on A than B?
- Should P-value be treated as binary (either significant as per predefined
  significance level or not significant)?
- Do we know the "direction" of impact from P-value (e.g. the way we can 
  interpret the correlation coefficient, ~1 -> higher positive correlation &
  ~-1 higher negative correlation)?
- Consequently, can we rank a list of categorical variables based on the P-
  values with the dependent variables?

Kindly also suggest me if there are alternative ways of achieving the above objectives.

Please let me know if I need to be more clear in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the questions in bullet points is **no**. And there is another approach, you need probably to fit some model. You didn't give much detail or context, so only: look into logistic or loglinear models, maybe.

Then your bulleted points:

- No, p-value does not measure strengt of effect, only strength of
  evidence. You need some measure of effect size.
- No, do not treat as binary. The numerical value keeps more
  information.
- No, p-value do not indicate direction of effect, in any way. You
  need some measure of effect size.
- No.

If you want more concrete proposals, we need much more context.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say C has higher impact on A than B?

No.  The p-value is a measure of the *strength of evidence* against the null hypothesis (statistical independence) in favour of the alternative hypothesis (statistical dependence).  It is not a measure of the strength of the dependence itself.  This distinction is often captured in the contrasting of "statistical significance versus practical significance".

> Should P-value be treated as binary (either significant as per predefined significance level or not significant)?

Not unless you have to.  The p-value captures more information than its reduction to the binary categories of "significant" or "non-significant", so it is best to keep and use the original p-value if possible.  In binary decision problems it is necessary to reduce things to a binary decision, so in this case the p-value is indeed treated as a binary, but even here it is useful to retain the value as contextual information.  Here I recommend you read [Wasserstein and Lazar (2016)](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108#.Vt2XIOaE2MN) (the ASA statement on p-values); this statement discusses the limitations of p-values and cautions against their reduction to binary classification for "significance".

> Do we know the "direction" of impact from p-value (e.g. the way we can interpret the correlation coefficient, ~1 -> higher positive correlation & ~-1 higher negative correlation)?

No.  The test-statistic in the chi-squared test is based on the sum-of-squared deviations from expected value over categories, which means that both positive and negative correlation of underlying variables will tend to manifest in larger values of the test-statistic (i.e., be more conducive to the alternative hypothesis).  The p-value is computed as a probability based on the null hypothesis when the underlying variables are independent.  The p-value does not show the direction of any underlying correlation between the variables.  (For this purpose the sample correlation matrix would be the most useful object.)

> Consequently, can we rank a list of categorical variables based on the p-values with the dependent variables?

It is unclear what exactly you are proposing here, but it does not sound useful.  In general, there are dangers that arise from comparing p-values across different hypothesis tests.  P-values taken across different hypothesis tests do not always obey sensible ranking desiderata, so they should be compared only with caution and skepticism.